# Vue CLI Updating cookie or updating store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I'm making a project with Vue, Node and also using Vuex. Now currently I'm storing user data in the cookie, not in the vuex store. But I came to a problem where I need to update user data in real-time, like when he buys something I need to update it's money on the webpage. Bow how do I change the value in the cookie? Is there are a way to update cookie or should I use the vuex store for this?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method for this would be to have the state in vuex and use a persistance plugin to persist parts (or all) of your vuex state.

You could use [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) for example.
It has built-in support for `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, etc..
To save your state to a cookie you could use [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie):

```
import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex';
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const vuexCookie = new VuexPersistence({
  restoreState: (key, storage) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
  saveState: (key, state, storage) =>
    Cookies.set(key, state, {
      expires: 3
    }),
  modules: ['user'] // only save the user module state in the cookie
});

const store = new Store({
  modules: {
    user: {
      state: {name: "User 1"},
      // TODO: getters, mutations, etc...
    },
    // ... more modules
  },
  plugins: [vuexCookie.plugin]
});
```

(Example modified from the [Detailed Example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) of *vuex-persist*)

You can specify a custom persistance strategy for every vuex module, so you can have different persistance strategies for different parts of your vuex state:

```
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
  storage: window.localStorage,
  reducer: (state) => ({ cache: state.cache }) //only save cache module
});
const vuexSession = new VuexPersistence({
  storage: window.sessionStorage,
  reducer: (state) => ({ user: state.user }) //only save user module
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user: { /* ... */ }, // will be stored in sessionStorage
    cache: { /* ... */ }, // will be stored in localStorage
    foobar: { /* ... */ } // not persisted, will reset on page reload
  },
  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin, vuexSession.plugin]
});
```

Comment: Okay. I'm confused at the moment what I should place in `key` `state` and `storage`

Comment: In `state` I've already set `user` like this: `user: VueCookie.get('user'),`

Comment: @zlotte here would be a working example with vuex: [vuex cookie example](https://jsfiddle.net/p2v54ztf/)  
If you only want to set the cookie you could also just use `VueCookie.set('user', yourUserObj, 30 /* expiry in days*/)`